# What lint rule causes text inside a <Text> element to align left inside of a JSX block within source code?

Tags: javascript, react-native, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

really simple question and i am sorry to bother people with it:

What rule is causing my text to align left in source - if i lint - my code will go from:

```
  <Button warning>
    <Text>
      Warning button
    </Text>
  </Button>
```

to:

```
  <Button warning>
    <Text>
Warning button
    </Text>
  </Button>
```

I can't find an answer with google - i would prefer to turn off this rule as I find it super ugly. I am using the AirBnb rules with react native.

My config is here: https://github.com/iamacup/choice/blob/master/.eslintrc in case this matters.

Comment: I think you should tell us what IDE you're using?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the IDE - i run ```yarn eslint --fix ./src``` in a terminal to actualy do the linting.

Comment: Hmm you're right. Was just guessing maybe the IDE is doing some magic

Comment: "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "eslint": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",

providing mine for reference

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: No @Kristoffer :(